# Why is my object not being set in AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I call a AsyncTask method to retrieve a entry from my room database. I do this in an AsyncTask as to not block the UI thread. In my doInBackGround method I assign a value to the object and we can see here it gets set:

[image]

On my post execute I call a method which uses this object. But it assigns as null and the program fails.

How come this value that I assigned in doInBackground didn't persist when I want to access in another method?

**AsyncTask**

```
 void getAtcUser(String username) {

    new getAtcUserAsyncTask(username).execute();
}

private class getAtcUserAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
   String name;


    getAtcUserAsyncTask(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        atcUserStats = mAtcDao.findByName(name);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        ATC_GameOver atc_gameOver = new ATC_GameOver();
        atc_gameOver.callOnChanged();
    }
}
```

**Retrieve assigned value**

```
public AtcUserStats getAtcUserStats(){
    return atcUserStats;
}
```

**callOnChanged**

```
public void callOnChanged() {


    mRepository = new UsersRepository(getApplication());
    AtcUser = mRepository.getAtcUserStats(); //Assgins null here - then program fails when I try access this object on the next line
    int singlesPlayed = AtcUser.getSinglesPlayed();
```

The error I am getting is a null object reference but how when I've assigned it previously? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I think inside doinbackground mAtcDao is null simply run a if condition stating that if(mAtcDao==null){
Toast.MakeText("It's Null")
}
Also try checking for atcUserStats  if matcdao is not null

Comment: Where is the callback implemented? I see you are creating a new callback every time.

Comment: @Mr.Patel mAtcDao is not null.

Comment: @CodeDaily what callback? callOnChanged is simply a method in another class that I use to store data to database. Well I would if I could get past the error.

Comment: what about atcUserStats ?

Comment: You should log each fields used in async and check which one is null

Comment: @Mr.Patel I manged to fix it will post answer but basically I passed AtcUserStats in post-execute in the CallOnChanged method and it worked rather than retrieving it in the callOnChanged Method.

Comment: @Mr.Patel Answer has been posted if you are curious.

Comment: atcUserStats should be returned from the doInBackground in place of the 'null`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I will try your suggestion because I ran into further problems later on because I created a new Instance of `= new ATC_GameOver();`  and lost all of my previous references. Could you expand on your answer in answers?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce atm When I try to return from `doInBackground`. `callOnChanged` is being called before `doInBackground` is reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manged to get it working. Rather than retrieving it in callOnChanged I passed it as a parameter to callOnChanged on post-execute and AtcUser was no longer null.

**AsyncTask**

```
 private class getAtcUserAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
   String name;


    getAtcUserAsyncTask(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        setAtcUserStats(mAtcDao.findByName(name));
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        ATC_GameOver atc_gameOver = new ATC_GameOver();
        atc_gameOver.callOnChanged(atcUserStats);
    }
}

private void setAtcUserStats(AtcUserStats byName) {
    atcUserStats = byName;
}
```

**callOnChanged**

```
public void callOnChanged(AtcUserStats atc_user) {


    mRepository = new UsersRepository(app);
    AtcUser = atc_user;
```